# Как называются переменные имеющие несколько значений?

Tags: javascript

Пример:

```
var mycar = {
   brand: "Honda",
   model: "Accord",
   year: 1998
 };
```

Comment: Такие переменные называются "объекты со свойствами". *("Такие решения - называются комплексными." Лосяш "Смешарики")*

Comment: То что указано в примере является объектом, но несколько значений могут также содержать и массивы.